# Would there be ocean currents in oceans of sulfuric acid?

Tags: science-based, physics, currents

**Would there be ocean currents in sulfuric acid oceans?**

For my world the oceans are made of sulfuric acid because of the high amount of sulfur in the atmosphere, and I was wondering whether there would be ocean currents in said oceans?

The atmosphere has 12 atm of pressure and temperature of 55 °C.

Comment: Assuming there is wind or the planet rotates I'd assume so, even expect so.

Comment: There is wind and the planet does rotate.

Comment: Depending on how pure said sulfuric acid is, you could also get something akin to thermohaline circulation, but with e.g. water instead of salt. I think. I am not a chemist.

Comment: Is there a moon/ is the place this is happening a moon? This will drive tides, keeping the ocean from coming into any kind of equilibrium and make for a pretty active ocean. Furthermore, winds drive surface water currents, so that right there is enough to keep at least some currents going.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currents are produced by gradients in the fluid hosting them: it can be a gradient in temperature, pressure, concentration, density, potential energy.

As long as at least a net gradient is present, a current will start. The substance subject to the gradient will only influence the rate at which the current will move, through its viscosity: hot water and hot molasses flow at different rate.

Comment: How come you never post things about your hot molasses ocean world, Dutch?  And the Pancake People?  Because in my heart I am there.

Comment: This answer is almost universally true.  Except ... the question says the air temperature is "55 °C" - no range, no variation.  Over millions of years the ocean will have equilibrated to precisely that temperature, and now all the currents will have stopped. :)  [Alright, I suppose salt leaching from land may still keep some flowing.  It's *hard* to calm an ocean...]

Comment: @MikeSerfas 55°c is the average temperature of the planet. The temperature ranges from 53°c to 57°c

Comment: @Willk, I posted something related [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/92435/30492) and [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/115342/30492)